# Writing in another file in python leaves my file empty

Tags: python, file

```
def enr_score(nom_jouer, n, con):
    score = open('Score.txt', 'a')

    seconds = time.time()
    local_time = time.ctime(seconds)

    score.write("Temp de registration: ")
    score.write(local_time)
    score.write("JOUER: ")
    score.write(nom_jouer)
    score.write("\n")
    score.write("Il/Elle a fini le jeu avec - ")
    score.write(n)
    score.write(" - disques apres - ")
    score.write(con)
    score.write(" - tentatives.")
    score.write("\n")

    score.close()

    return "Ton score a ete enregistre!"
```

I got this code but for some reason when I check the Score.txt file it's empty. Shouldn't something be written in it?
There's no errors btw

This is the code that calls the function btw

```
nom_jouer = input("\nComment vous appelez vous? \n \nUSERNAME: ") #demande le nom de jouer

from Partie_E import enr_score

nr_disq = str(n)
tent = str(con)

enr_score(nom_jouer, nr_disq, tent)
```

Comment: Can you check your indentation? I'm not sure if it is just the way it was pasted in, but  your line starting with `def` should be one tab to the left of the rest of the code.

Comment: it's a function called "enr_score" that writes the score of the player in it

Comment: right, but is the code below it indented?  The question in stackoverflow shows no indentation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code fails to parse at the second line, and there is nothing to call your function.  Also, it doesn't take 12 separate `writ` commands to illustrate the problem.

Comment: not sure what indented means but it's supposed to have a "tab" in front of it if that's what you mean

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So, basically I was a bit dumb (I'm relatively new to programming) and didn't realize I was editing another file than the one I was looking at.

It created the file in an outside folder and I thought it would edit the already existing one in the same folder as the .py files.

Sorry for the mind-F.